# Progress Bar not visible while PromptForChoice is active in terminal

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I'm trying to create a script for adding junctions from my OneDrive folder to specific locations on my computer, so the files are synced to the cloud.

All possible junctions are stored in a array list and idea is that I get a prompt for each one. I use for the prompt `$Host.UI.PromptForChoice`

```
Clear-Host
$Host.UI.RawUI.CursorPosition = @{ x = 0; y = 10 }
Write-Progress -Activity "Adding Junctions" -Status "$PercentageComplete% ($CurrentItem/$TotalItems) completed" -PercentComplete $PercentageComplete

foreach ($Item in $List) {
  ## Progress Bar
  $CurrentItem++
  $PercentageComplete = [int](($CurrentItem / $TotalItems) * 100)
  Write-Progress -Activity "Adding Junctions" -Status "$PercentageComplete% ($CurrentItem/$TotalItems) completed" -PercentComplete $PercentageComplete -CurrentOperation $Item.Name

  if($PromptActive) {
    ## Choice Prompt
    $Title    = $Item.Name
    $Question = "Add junction?"
    $Choices = New-Object Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]
    $Choices.Add((New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription -ArgumentList '&Yes', 'Adds the junction for selected program'))
    $Choices.Add((New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription -ArgumentList '&No', 'Skips the creating of a junction for selected program'))
    $Choices.Add((New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription -ArgumentList '&All', 'Skips the prompt, and creates a junction for all programms'))
    
    $Decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($Title, $Question, $Choices, 0)
  }

  switch($Decision) {
    { $_ -eq 0 } {
      Add-Junction($Item)
    }
    { $_ -eq 1 } {
      Write-Host -BackgroundColor DarkRed " Skipping" $Item.Name " " 
    }
    { $_ -eq 2 } {
      $PromptActive = $false
      Add-Junction($Item)
    }
  }
}
```

When I start the script, the progressbar is not visible, after submitting the first prompt the progressbar is for a sliptsecond visible. When I add a `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500` it's visible the whole time while the sleep is active, but disappears again when the prompt shows up.

Why is it that $Host.UI.PromptForChoice lets the progressbar disappear? Is there a workaround?

Comment: You are prompting for one item at a time. so the PB is only see for that item. This is not PFC causing this, it's doing what you asked it to do. Show PB for the item being worked on. PB only stay if there is more active processing happening. Again, that is not what your code is doing. PB are not really a tool to be interrupted, they are a tool to report the start and end of a specific activity. As documented; ***The ```Write-Progress``` cmdlet displays a progress bar in a PowerShell command window that depicts the status of a running command or script.*** If you interrupt it, it stops.